# Does Capybara Webkit recognize JavaScript's Array.includes() method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

In my Rails app front-end I use JavaScript's [`Array.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method as follows

```
if (['a', 'b', 'c'].includes('b')) {
  // do stuff
```

It works fine in a live Chrome browser, but my RSpec test is failing. I believe Capybara Webkit doesn't seem to support it?

I can confirm this by pausing the spec with `binding.pry` and running

```
> page.evaluate_script("['a', 'b', 'c'].includes('b')")
=> nil
```

It returns `nil` when it should return `true`.

Just out of curiosity I tried this same thing on another Rails app, and miraculously it worked on that app

```
> page.evaluate_script("['a', 'b', 'c'].includes('b')")
=> true
```

So I'm scratching my head as to why it would work on one app but not another?

- App #1 (Failure)

  - Capybara `2.18.0`
  - Capybara Webkit `1.15.0`
- App #2 (Success)

  - Capybara `2.13.0`
  - Capybara Webkit `1.14.0`

In fact the first app where it failed seems to have a more recent version of Capybara/Webkit..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`capybara-webkit` gets it's JS support based on the version of QtWebkit it is built against.  The last released stable version of QtWebkit supported ES5 (and most of ES 5.1) and is basically equivalent to a 6-7 year old version of Safari.

Since `Array.prototype.includes()` wasn't included in the JS standard until ES2015 it is not supported natively by `capybara-webkit`.  You can however add support for `includes` via a polyfill and I'm guessing that's what you have in your App #2.

In order for `capybara-webkit` to be useful with modern apps you need to make sure all JS used in your app is transpiled to ES5 and polyfilled (using babel, etc). If your apps requirements don't include old/obsolete browsers a better solution for headless testing is to use headless Chrome or Firefox via capybaras selenium driver since those combinations support modern JS and CSS.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs, execute_script will perform and javascript much better, I have replaced evaluate with execute in my e2e tests